# not able to build spotlight index without huge amounts of my harddrive being used

Tags: memory, spotlight

I had to rebuild my spotlight index a long time ago for reasons I have forgotten.  The memory on my harddrive dropped from 300 gigs to about 150 gigs and it was losing about 1 gig every 5 minutes.  I then tried to rebuild the spotlight index only using the files under a single user, so I excluded quite a bit of files.  Same thing happened but this time the space on my computer went down to 25 gigs and it was continuing to diminish.  So I can't index my files and search for something otherwise my harddisk will have no memory.

Comment: What makes you believe that Spotlight is consuming so much space? What is the question you want answered?

Comment: Did you read: "The memory on my harddrive dropped from 300 gigs to about 150 gigs and it was losing about 1 gig every 5 minutes."?

Comment: To confirm this, clear Spotlight again by dragging all volumes into the Privacy tab. Wait a few minutes, reboot. Check disk space.

Comment: Yea, that prevents Spotlight from using huge amounts of disc space but now spotlight cannot find anything.

Comment: Let’s unify this on your new question with more details. For future reference, [making a substantial edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/editing) will [bump any question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers).